# Visual Studio 2017 Build Issue - Solution with 5 projects

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have one project in a solution that will not build and shows multiple errors.

The projects are written in VB.NET and 4 of the 5 projects build fine.

The project that will not build is a "Business Layer" class, and each class file in the project must inherit from a similar named class in a separate data layer class library project (which does build without errors.)

A typical error shows "Type 'DeductionDC' is not defined", and the source line where this error occurs is as follows...

Public Class Deduction
Inherits DeductionDC

The DeductionDC class is in the separate data layer class project, and the business layer project references this data layer classes project.

What's more, when I click on the error and the source file opens in the business layer project, the error goes away and the total number of errors shown goes down. If I continue to double-click on the errors, the errors are eliminated and the total # of errors continue to go down.

Unfortunately, there are 1924 errors, so after I got down to about 1500 remaining, I decided to do a rebuild to make sure that my efforts where working. When I did, the # of errors went back up to 1924, and the errors that I had fixed were once again appearing as errors.

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with this. I have an identical solution in VS2010 and have compared the setups back-and-forth and they appear to be correct. All of the necessary "references" are within the Business Layer project, yet it fails to properly see the DataLayer project.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, closing VS, re-opening and then doing a full build, but nothing seems to work. At this point, I'm looking for some guidance on how to correct this.

Thank you!
Bob Hill

Comment: `1924 errors` Are those actual build errors, or just Intellisense "errors"? The latter is known to be less than reliable at times. You can tell the difference by looking at the `Output` tab, or by filtering the `Errors` tab to show `Build only` entries.

Comment: Looks like either all of your project not targetted to same .NET framework or project references not updated.

Comment: I think this was the answer Bhasyakarulu. For some reason the target framework was set to .NET 3.5 for this project. Once I changed that, I'm down to 5 errors. Now I need to look into those. Thanks for the help!!